# Can't load local JS file after migrate from UIWebView to WKWebView in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have UIWebView like this:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "DataProvider.h"

@implementation QHArticle
{
    UIWebView *_helperWebView;
}

-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _helperWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
        [_helperWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><script src='Article.js'></script><body onload='Article.init();'></body></html>" baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString*)callJSMethod:(NSString*)method
{
    return [_helperWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:method];
}

-(NSArray *)listArticle
{
    NSString *json = [self callJSMethod:@"(function() {return JSON.stringify(Article._data.news)})()"];
    ;
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&error];
    return [result subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, result.count-2)];
}
```

The codes above is working fine when i tried it. But, after the codes changed to WKWebView like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#import "DataProvider.h"

@implementation QHArticle
{
    WKWebView *_helperWebView;
}

-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _helperWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] init];
        [_helperWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><script src='Article.js'></script><body onload='Article.init();'></body></html>" baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)callJSMethod:(NSString *)method
{
    __block NSString *resultString = nil;
    __block BOOL finished = NO;

    [_helperWebView evaluateJavaScript:method completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            if (result != nil) {
                resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"evaluateJavaScript error : %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
        finished = YES;
    }];

    while (!finished)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }

    return resultString;
}
```

I got an error message, "evaluateJavaScript error : .... Can't find Article object" and got white blank screen on the phone.
I still can't find the issues after i migrated it to WKWebView, please help.
I just want to use Objective-C, not Swift because this is the legacy code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The WKWebView won't load anything from a `file://` URL.

Start by loading your `Article.js` script into a string; you can use `evaluateJavaScript:` to run it.

To inject a string into every page that a particular WKWebView loads, you would create a `WKUserScript`, attach it to a `WKUserContentController`, and attach THAT to a `WKWebViewConfiguration`.

Then create your WKWebView with `[WKWebView initWithFrame:configuration:]`

Comment: Can you give me an example about this? i want to load the javascript and listArticle can run successful.